# How to define bean for parameter 2 of AuthenticationManager with spring security 6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new in spring security 6. When I tried to config security, I got this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of constructor in com.security.Security.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have defined bean in config file, and method to signin, signup. Since I add signin api, I got error.

SecurityConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration{
    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService, JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }
    private JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/admin").hasAnyAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name())
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/user").hasAnyAuthority(Role.USER.name())
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(
                        jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                );
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JWTService jwtService;
    public User signup(SignUpRequest signUpRequest){
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail());
        user.setName(signUpRequest.getName());
        user.setRole(Role.USER);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public JwtAuthenticationResponse signin(SignInRequest signInRequest){
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(signInRequest.getEmail(),signInRequest.getPassword()));
        var user = userRepository.findByEmail(signInRequest.getEmail()).orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid email or password"));
        var jwt = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        var refreshToken = jwtService.generatefreshToken(new HashMap<>(),user);
        JwtAuthenticationResponse jwtAuthenticationResponse = new JwtAuthenticationResponse();
        jwtAuthenticationResponse.setToken(jwt);
        jwtAuthenticationResponse.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        return jwtAuthenticationResponse;
    }
}
```

How can I define correctly bean and what wrong in my code? Can someone explain the parameter in?

Comment: For anyone reading this question in the future, the code above is not secure and is handing out JWTs straight to clients which is VERY dangerous. This code should NOT be used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add Bean annotation for AuthenticationManager in security configuration class :

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Maybe useful; with @RequiredArgsConstructor you don't no longer need to define a constructor for SecurityConfiguration class. it's would be more simple without :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
  private final JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
  private final UserService userService;
 //...
}
```